# Blender Crash on .fbx export

Tags: animation, export, .fbx, unreal-engine

So I finally finished my 1st animation in blender and wanted to check it on UE4. I tried to export it but when I click export, doesn't technically crash but it stops responding and into "thinking" mode. It works when I disable animations but I need them. I'm mostly a beginner in this stuff so any help will be appreciated.

Edit: Deactivated "All Actions". It works now

I'm using blender version 2.79b on Windows 10.

Comment: For me, running Blender 2.83 on Windows, the solution was to reboot my computer. ¯\\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tips to avoid this:

- Activate Selected Objects (not whole scene)
- Activate only "Deform Bones" under Armature tab(so rig won't corrupt the FBX if many constraints, or loopback bones that might make it bug - will also export in a clean way, etc)
- Disactivate "All Actions" from Animation tab (so that rig will export only it's aniamtion clips, not the whole scene animation
- Make sure that SDS is at a reasonable level of Render Settings (1 or 2 max), SDS at 3 or 4 will take a long time to "Apply Modifiers" to the mesh - specially if it's a whole scene. You can optionally turn this "Apply Render setting modifiers" off under Geometries tab

Then export and the software won't have to think so hard or ultimately crash.

Comment: tnx for your help